# mvc 4 validations using DataAnnotatoins

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

Am practising MVC4 validations and got some basic idea. But am not sure where the Error message comes from in my below code and how to **override the  message**

My model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Contact number field is required.")]
        public int ContactNumber { get; set; }
```

when i leave the field empty am getting

> Contact number field is required

but when i type any string and submit am getting

> The value 'string i typed' is not valid for ContactNumber

how to override my error message ?

Comment: It is Clientside validation

Comment: type any number and see whether the model passes

Comment: yes number will work but my question is how to override the message ?

Answer (score 1):

Add this validation to your propery which matches for valid number. This way you can override it.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Contact number field is required.")]
[RegularExpression(@"[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+", ErrorMessage = "Contact number must be a Number.")]
public int ContactNumber { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you added was in the "Required" attribute, so it only gets used when something fails the "Required" check, ie. when it is left blank. If you want a particular message for when it's not a number then you'll need to add an attribute to check for that too, and give it a custom error message. A regex should do it. As a nice side effect of this, you can also take the opportunity to do some more detailed checking here, like making sure it's actually in phone number format with the right number of digits and stuff, rather than just checking that the value is numeric.